# Logging Queries Generated by Triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, logging

Is there a way to log queries generated by triggers in MySQL in the General Query Log? My General Query Log doesn't seem to pick these up.

Also, if a query generated by a trigger exceeds the threshold for slow queries, will it be logged in the slow query log?

Answer (score 2):

Yup, via [binary log for stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-logging.html)